# Can a Cython/Numba compiled function improve on numpy.max(numpy.abs(a-b))?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, numba

I am optimizing a bottleneck section of my code--iterating on a function a' = f(a), where a and a' are N by 1 vectors, until max(abs(a' - a)) is sufficiently small.

I have put a Numba wrapper on f(a), and got a nice speedup over the most optimized pure NumPy version I was able to produe (cut runtime by about 50%).

I tried writing a C-compatible version of numpy.max(numpy.abs(aprime - a)), but it turns out this is slower! I actually lose back ALL of the gains I got from Numba-fying the first portion of the iteration!

Is there likely to be a way for Numba or Cython to improve upon numpy.max(numpy.abs(aprime - a))? I reproduce my code below for reference, where a is P0 and a' is Pprime:

EDIT: For me, it seems that it is important to "flatten()" the inputs to "maxabs()". When I do this, the performance is no worse than NumPy. Then, when I do a "dry run" of the function outside the timing brackets as JoshAdel suggested, the loop with "maxabs" does slightly better than the loop with numpy.max(numpy.abs()).

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

### Preliminaries, to make the working example fully functional

n = 1200
Gammer = np.exp(-np.random.rand(n,n))

alpher = np.ones((n,1))
xxer = 10000*np.random.rand(n,1)

chii = 6.5
varkappa = 6.5
phi3 = 1.5
A = .5
sig = .2 

mmer = np.dot(Gammer,xxer**phi3)


totalprod = A*alpher + (1-A)*mmer
Gammerchii = Gammer**chii
Gammerrats = Gammerchii[:,0].flatten()/Gammerchii[0,:].flatten()
Gammerrats[(Gammerchii[0,:].flatten() == 0) | (Gammerchii[:,0].flatten() == 0)] = 1.
P0 = (Gammerrats*(xxer[0]/totalprod[0])*(totalprod/xxer).flatten())**(1/(1+2*chii))
P0 *= n/np.sum(P0)
### End of preliminaries

### This is the function to produce a' = f(a)
@jit
def Piteration(P0, chii, sig, n, xxer, totalprod, Gammerrats, Gammerchii):
    Mac = np.zeros((n,))
    Pprime = np.zeros((n,))
    themacpow = 1-(1/chii)*(sig/(1-sig))
    specialchiipow = 1/(1+2*chii)
    Psum = 0.

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            Mac[j] += ((P0[i]/P0[j])**chii)*Gammerchii[i,j]*totalprod[j]

    for i in range(n):
        Pprime[i] = (Gammerrats[i]*(xxer[0]/totalprod[0])*(totalprod[i]/xxer[i])*((Mac[i]/Mac[0])**themacpow))**specialchiipow
        Psum += Pprime[i]

    Psum = n/Psum

    for i in range(n):
        Pprime[i] *= Psum

    return Pprime

### This is the function to find max(abs(aprime - a))
@jit
def maxabs(vec1,vec2,n):
    themax = 0.
    curdiff = 0.
    for i in range(n):
        curdiff = vec1[i] - vec2[i]
        if curdiff < 0:
            curdiff *= -1
        if curdiff > themax:
            themax = curdiff
    return themax

### This is the main loop
diff = 1000.
while diff > 1e-2:
    Pprime = Piteration(P0.flatten(),  chii,  sig,  n,  xxer.flatten(), totalprod.flatten(), Gammerrats.flatten(),  Gammerchii)

    diff = maxabs(P0.flatten(),Pprime.flatten(),n)
    P0 = 1.*Pprime
```

Comment: _"I tried writing a C-compatible version [...] but it turns out this is slower"_ - can you show us this implementation?

Comment: The implementation is as above. By "C-compatible" what I mean is it uses loops instead of vectorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I time your `maxabs` function vs `np.max(np.abs(vec1 - vec2))` for an array of shape `(1200,)`, the numba version is ~2.6x faster using numba 0.32.0.

When you time the code, make sure you run your function once before you time it so that you don't include the time it takes to jit the code, which you only pay the first time. In general using `timeit` and running multiple times takes care of this. I'm not sure how you did the timing though since I see almost no difference in using `maxabs` vs the numpy call, most of the runtime seems to be in the call to `Piteration`.

Comment: I am timing the code using "time.time()"--record the time before each while loop and record the time after, and take the difference.

Comment: One thing I found makes a difference for me--if I ".flatten()" the inputs to maxabs, it runs faster.

Comment: AND--I have tried doing a "dry run" of maxabs() outside the timing brackets, and this seems to "fix" the "problem". With the "dry run" to jit the function first, the recorded time for Numba is slightly better. But, as you find also, the gain is not big--less than 10%.